# XML schema/format for representing a generic file format?

Tags: xml, metadata, file-format

Is there an existing XML schema that can be used to describe a generic file format?  Something that would have tags that say things like "The file has a header that is x bytes long", "The first element of the header is a 4 byte unsigned integer that represents the length of the file", etc. ?  I need a format of this sort and wanted to make sure there was not an existing standard one before I come up with one myself, since it seems like the kind of thing that might already be out there.  Unfortunately, my Google searches have led me nowhere, but I don't know if that's because there's nothing out there or I just don't know the right search terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider what has been done by [x12.org](http://x12.org/) for EDI.  Their file formats are commerce oriented, but may cover what you have in mind.

Comment: That didn't quite cover what I needed, ended up having to make my own. Thanks though!